# Android SQLite DB query not returning results

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite DB set up for my application and I have plenty of DB transactions that work but for some reason one of the queries does not return any results. Any Suggestions are greatly appreciated. The query looks like this:

```
Log.d("DEBUG EXPREPORTS", "SELECTING report id 1");
        expList = expData.queryHelper2("SELECT * FROM " 
                +MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES +" WHERE reportid = " 
+ "'"+ 1 +"'", null);
```

queryHelper2:

```
public List<ExpensesFields> queryHelper2(String query, String[] selectionArgs){

        List<ExpensesFields> queryResults = new ArrayList<ExpensesFields>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);

         cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              ExpensesFields expense = cursorToexpense(cursor);
              queryResults.add(expense);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return queryResults;
    }
```

Through Debugging I know that there is a record that has a reportid = 1. Also In the above query the syntax seems to be correct because changing reportid to id (the table key) returns the correct result.

Also this Query:

```
expList = expData.queryHelper2("SELECT * FROM " 
                +MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES +" WHERE reportid !=
 " + "'"+ 1 +"'", null);
```

returns all of the rows. And I add items to the table with the following code:

```
expData = new ExpensesDataSource(getActivity());
            expData.open();
            expData.createExpenses("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",Integer.parseInt(reportID.getText().toString()));
```

and createExpenses looks like:

```
public ExpensesFields createExpenses( String type ,String paidVia,String amount,String employee,
            String job,String extra,String costcode,String account,String task,String date,
            String vendor,String receipt,String city,String purpose,String description, int reportid ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_TYPE, type);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_PAIDVIA, paidVia);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_EMPLOYEE, employee );
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_JOB, job);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_EXTRA, extra);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_COSTCODE, costcode);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_ACCOUNT, account);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_TASK, task);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_DATE, date);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_VENDOR, vendor);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_RECEIPT, receipt);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_CITY, city);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_PURPOSE, purpose);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.EXPENSES_COLUMN_REPORTID, reportid);
        long insertId = database.insert(
                MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, null,
            values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES,
            allColumns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ExpensesFields newexpense = cursorToexpense(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newexpense;
      }
```

I'm really stumped so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're matching the id as a string. Any chance there's some whitespace in the data, and the column is not of type `INTEGER`?

Comment: The column is of type integer. I have not checked for white space I will do that now. Is there a way to eliminate white space from the result?

Comment: I have also added the code that I use to add entries to the db

Comment: If `reportid` is INTEGER the SELECT statement should  be "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES + " WHERE reportid = " + 1

Comment: so why then when its the table key which is also an int, the code I have above works fine

Comment: also @ramaral if you post that as an actually answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: `so why then when its the table key ...` I can't explain that. I always use KEY_ID "=" + longValue

Comment: Alright well thank you for your response